# How to change data type when running query (not inside PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

### Explanation

When doing precision math on decimals inside MySQL, it handles strings as Float and not Fixed for example if we have following column in database (amount type is `DECIMAL(43,20)`)

```
+--------------------------+
|         amount           |
+--------------------------+
|  0.20000000000000000000  |
+--------------------------+
```

running the following PHP code

```
$amount_to_add = "0.1";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table SET amount = amount + :amount");
$stmt->bindValue("amount", $amount_to_add);
$stmt->execute();
```

would result this:

```
+--------------------------+
|         amount           |
+--------------------------+
|  0.30000000000000004000  |
+--------------------------+
```

notice the additional 0.0000000000000000**4000**

its because `$amount_to_add` was string

As i need to use BC Math functions, its output is **always string**

`And i can't convert it to double/float inside PHP because it will lose precision and decimal points`

### Questions

How should i pass this to MySQL to treat it as decimal(fixed) and not string (float) which doesn't require changing string type inside PHP?

Is something like declaring the datatype when running query possible? so it changes string to decimal inside MySQL

Comment: MySQL handles strings as strings, float as floats and decimals as, wait for it, decimals.

Comment: @Strawberry Well, the issue is obvious as i explained, do you have a possible solution maybe? i'm really stuck between php's `losing precision` and MySQL's `string to float` behavior

Comment: Can you do the calculation in php via `bcadd` and then update the result in mysql?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Consider providing proper DDLs, sample data, and a desired result.

Comment: @FuzzyTree There are too many updates to each row (maybe +500 in a second) i don't think doing calculation in PHP is possible/efficient while keeping the sum updated

Comment: Have you tried `amount = amount + CAST(:amount AS DECIMAL(X, Y))`?

Comment: @Uueerdo you should post that as an answer. That worked for me

Comment: @Strawberry Check the Uueerdo answer below, just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean it's unclear... thanks anyways for downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET amount = amount + CAST(:amount AS DECIMAL(X, Y))
```